# Getting value from QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidgetitem

I want to set `QTableWidgetItem`'s data as an image. *imagePath* may be different each time.

```
QTableWidgetItem *itemMedia = new QTableWidgetItem();
itemMedia->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
itemMedia->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap(imagePath).scaled(width, 100, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
m_table->setItem(0,0,itemMedia);
m_table->setItem(0,1,itemMedia);
m_table->setItem(1,0,itemMedia);
m_table->setItem(1,1,itemMedia);
```

I've created it nicely. Next, I want to get data with this:

```
connect(m_table, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *)), this, SLOT(onItemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *)));

void MUCSharedMedia::onItemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *item)
{
    qDebug()<<"DecorationRole: " <<item->data(Qt::DecorationRole).toString();
    qDebug()<<"DisplayRole: " <<item->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
}
```

Actually I want *imagePath* in one of this role , but I get this line in **Application Console**:

```
DecorationRole:  ""
DisplayRole:  ""
```

How to get value? Any suggestion?

**EDITED:**
I want to show image on each **QTableWidgetItem** after that I want to store image path of images which I've shown.

Comment: Do you want to store imagePath as string in each item? Then try to use DisplayRole in both cases? Or you want to store actual image, please  clarify

Comment: I want to set image and get image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store `QString` actually, you need `DisplayRole` two times:

```
itemMedia->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, imagePath);

qDebug()<<"DisplayRole: " <<item->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
```

EDIT: if you need to show image and get image file path I suggest you another way:

1) Set image like you did:

```
itemMedia->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap(imagePath).scaled(width, 100, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
```

2) Set image path using `Qt::UserRole`

```
itemMedia->setData(Qt::UserRole, imagePath);
```

When you need it:

```
qDebug()<<"File Path: " <<item->data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
```

But application will use image for displaying.

Comment: I answered about QImage from filepath but same way you can get related image class you need

Comment: I want to setData as an actual image and get data as a qstring

Comment: @afn: you said from the very beginning you want to store imagePath in each item

Comment: yes, but it was just last part. I want to show image on each QTableWidgetItem after that I want to store image path of images which I've shown.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with all these details so it would be clear what you actually need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96682/discussion-between-afn-and-demonplus).

Comment: @afn I added information which you wanted to my answer

Answer (score 1):

`QTableWidgetItem::data()` returns `QVariant` where you'll get the data with `QVariant::value()`.

Alternatively, use `QTableWidget::text()`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html

Answer (score 1):

You store a QPixmap:

```
itemMedia->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap(imagePath).scaled(width, 100, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
```

but try to extract it as a QString:

```
qDebug()<<"DecorationRole: " <<item->data(Qt::DecorationRole).toString();
```

That will always give you a default-constructed (i.e. empty) QString.

You want to retrieve it as a QPixmap:

```
item->data(Qt::DecorationRole).value<QPixmap>()
```

(though there's little point sending that to a QDebug stream!)

There's a good chance you want the original, unscaled pixmap.  In which case, you'll need to store that as well, perhaps in `Qt::UserRole`:

```
itemMedia->setData(Qt::UserRole, QPixmap(imagePath));
```

and change the retrieval to match.